# wait.until in selenium WD does not return

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I just started learning selenium WD.  I am using firefox, & java 1.8 & eclipse in my mac.  In the following code, I am trying to print the lowest price value from
orbitz.com web site.

When I get to wait.until toward the end of the code, it gets stuck & does not return.  I can not figure out why & need some help resolving this problem.

```
package fh2_orbitzWD;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class WDDemo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,   
         IOException{
    WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
    wd.get("http://www.orbitz.com");

    wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='search.type']")).click();

    //Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebDriverWait  wait = new WebDriverWait(wd,60);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name        
        ("ar.rt.leaveSlice.orig.key")));

    wd.findElement(By.name("ar.rt.leaveSlice.orig.key")).clear();
    wd.findElement(By.name("ar.rt.leaveSlice.orig.key")).sendKeys("DFW");

    wd.findElement(By.name("ar.rt.leaveSlice.dest.key")).clear();
    wd.findElement(By.name("ar.rt.leaveSlice.dest.key")).sendKeys("SFO");

    wd.findElement(By.name("ar.rt.leaveSlice.date")).clear();
    wd.findElement(By.name("ar.rt.leaveSlice.date")).sendKeys("5/15/2015");

    wd.findElement(By.name("ar.rt.returnSlice.date")).clear();
    wd.findElement(By.name("ar.rt.returnSlice.date")).sendKeys("5/25/2015");

    System.out.println("Right before the click of search");

    wd.findElement(By.name("search")).click();

    WebDriverWait  wait2 = new WebDriverWait(wd,80);

    wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//* 
        [@id='resultsTwoColumn']")));***



    String price = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='money small-
        cents']")).getText();


    System.out.println("Price is: " + price);   

    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you waited more than 80 seconds?

Comment: Yes I have tried & still have same results.  Can not get final print value.